# Jenkins Build fails when artifacts are not there

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, artifacts

I use Jenkins to run some integration tests on a web appilcation (using cucumber, capybara and selenium)

Everytime a test fails, a screenshot, the HTML source and a video of the process is saved.

the path structure looks like this:

```
results/output/<test_name>/<files>
```

I use the archive artifacts feature of Jenkins to provide the files (pattern: `results/output/*/*`). It works great.

However as soon as a build succeeds, there are no screenshots/videos etc... and the build fails because Jenkins cannot find the files for the pattern.

**Is there a way to tell Jenkins to succeed without having the files present?**

I don't want to do a dirty hack which involves creating an empty folder structure like result/output/success/hooray.txt.

Comment: Good question; I was wondering about the exact same thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue on a couple of our projects.  There are two different ways we have resolved it (on two different builds).

1) Added a command to the build steps that creates a bogus temporary file if no files already existed.

In this case, it was meant to collect an output.pdf file that would be generated if the tests failed.  I added a build step where if that file did not exist we created a "missing.pdf" file.  Then what I collect as artifacts is '*.pdf' from the given directory.  This seems to work out pretty well.

2) On another build we needed to collect a set of files using a glob.

What we did here was made it so the build step always creates a single empty file in the destination area.  That way the glob always matches something.

Those are the best solutions we have found so far.  If you find something better I would love to hear about it.

Comment: I added a step that created a success.txt when the folder was empty after the build

Answer (score 13):

There's an open issue on for that: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10502

The behavior is controlled by the system property `hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver.warnOnEmpty`, as explained on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

Comment: +1, I think this is the correct answer. (If anyone else is wondering how to get this working with Jenkins running on Debian/Ubuntu,  edit `/etc/default/jenkins` and put `-Dhudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver.warnOnEmpty=true` in **JAVA_ARGS** (or possibly JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS). JENKINS_ARGS won't work, at least if you have more than one -D property!

Comment: Still, as someone comments in the issue you linked to, shame that this can't be configured with a checkbox in Jenkins UI on a per-job basis.